# How to change date format in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, date-formatting

I have dataframe which is using 2 parameters:

```
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=l_header, data=conv)
```

With below content:

```
  column_1                    date
0      XYZ  04/11/2016 09:13:55 AM
1      QAZ  05/10/2019 11:31:05 PM
2      WSX  12/08/2019 08:00:00 AM
```

How can I change date column format (it's a string) from:

```
%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p
```

to:

```
%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) methods from the built-in [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module to use in the [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) function that will go into the brackets of the [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) method:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = {"column_1": ["XYZ", "QAZ", "WSX"],
      "date": ["04/11/2016 09:13:55 AM", "05/10/2019 11:31:05 PM", "12/08/2019 08:00:00 AM"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

format1 ="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"
format2 = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
df["date"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, format1).strftime(format2))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  column_1                 date
0      XYZ  2016-04-11 09:13:55
1      QAZ  2019-05-10 23:31:05
2      WSX  2019-12-08 08:00:00
```

---

**UPDATE:**

As pointed out by @YevKad in the comments, there is no need to import `datetime`, as `pandas` comes with its own `datetime` section:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {"column_1": ["XYZ", "QAZ", "WSX"],
      "date": ["04/11/2016 09:13:55 AM", "05/10/2019 11:31:05 PM", "12/08/2019 08:00:00 AM"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

format1 ="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"
format2 = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format=format1).dt.strftime(format2)

print(df)
```

Comment: if you want to avoid using `apply` you can do this: `df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format=format1).dt.strftime(format2)`

Comment: In your update, the final `df['date']` is of type object rather than datetime!

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be the most convenient way?

```
>>> df
  column_1                    date
0      XYZ  04/11/2016 09:13:55 AM
1      QAZ  05/10/2019 11:31:05 PM
2      WSX  12/08/2019 08:00:00 AM

>>> df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

  column_1                date
0      XYZ 2016-04-11 09:13:55
1      QAZ 2019-05-10 23:31:05
2      WSX 2019-12-08 08:00:00
```

But it's best if you do this during the loading of the .csv file

```
>>> data_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=l_header, 
        parse_dates=['date'], 
        infer_datetime_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```